# How to align second column of second row to the same first column or first row in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I align **Text1** label the same postion **Text3** label as below: 
http://www.bootply.com/R2CkWnzZQq#. Actually, I don't like to use custom css to adjust Text3 label. Below is html code:

```
<br class="clearfix">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-text-title">Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <hr>
<div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <br class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Report" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text3</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Demo" name="Demo" placeholder="Text" rows="3" style="min-width:100%;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Description" class="col-sm-1 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-11">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with following

```
<br class="clearfix">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-text-title">Header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <hr>    
        <div class="row">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 control-label text-right">Text1</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" value="" type="text">
            </div>  
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 control-label text-right">Text1</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clearfix">

        <div class="row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 control-label text-right">Text3</label>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Demo" name="Demo" placeholder="Text" rows="3" style="min-width:100%;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clearfix">

        <div class="row">
            <div for="name" class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code. I'd tested on the link you shared and it works. Cheers! :-)

```
<br class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Report" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text3</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Demo" name="Demo" placeholder="Text" rows="3" style="min-width:100%;"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

What i did here is straightforward , I'd changed the `col-sm-12` to `col-sm-6` to follow top labels , `col-sm-2 control-label` to `col-sm-3 control-label` , and textarea div of `col-sm-10` to `col-sm-9`

**EDIT 1**: Fiddling around with div cols works

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <h2>Info</h2>
    <hr>
<div class="form-horizontal">

          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Text1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label">Text2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Text" name="Text" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>

        <br class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Report" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Text3</label>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id="Demo" name="Demo" placeholder="Text" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Description" class="col-sm-1 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-11">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I want to keep the textbox 3 with the size of width big from left to right as I expected from the link.

Comment: @nvtthang i'd fiddled around with the link and its weird that `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8` can works but your `col-sm-6` cannot

Comment: @nvtthang see if [this](http://www.bootply.com/2qh7uto6MT) is the result you want